# Trying to access sharepoint list using python

Tags: python, authentication, sharepoint, python-requests, sharepoint-online

I have full access to the resource I would like to connect to the Microsoft.sharepoint.c0m site lists.

I would like to know what is the easiest way to pull or upload the data from sharepoint list in python? I am getting error code 403 with this code:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
auth = HttpNtlmAuth('username', 'password')

r = requests.get("https://sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items",
verify=False,
auth=auth,
)
```

Why am I getting error code 403 ?

Answer (score 5):

[HttpNtlmAuth](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm) is supposed to be utilized via HTTP NTLM authentication which is **not** supported in *SharePoint Online*.

Instead you could consider [Office365-REST-Python-Client library](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client).The following example demonstrates how to authenticate via user credentials and read list items in SharePoint Online:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
ffrom office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  list_object = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(listTitle)
  items = list_object.get_items()
  ctx.load(items)
  ctx.execute_query()

  for item in items:
      print("Item title: {0}".format(item.properties["Title"]))
```

Comment: I tried this code now but I think it does not work anymore. Are there any new solution for this job?